# std::forward test in template and non-template function

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I have the following code directly from : 
http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html

compiled at g++ 4.8.1 as : g++ -std=c++11 testforward.cpp -o testforward.exe

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>   
#include <algorithm> 

class X
{
    std::vector<double> data;
public:
    X():
        data(100000) // lots of data
    {}
    X(X const& other): // copy constructor
        data(other.data)   // duplicate all that data
    {}
    X(X&& other):  // move constructor
        data(std::move(other.data)) // move the data: no copies
    {}

    X& operator=(X const& other) // copy-assignment
    {
        data=other.data; // copy all the data
        return *this;
    }

    X& operator=(X && other) // move-assignment
    {
        data=std::move(other.data); // move the data: no copies
        return *this;
    }
};



void g(X&& t)
{
    std::cout << "t in g is rvalue" << std::endl ;
}
void g(X& t)
{
    std::cout << "t in g is lvalue" << std::endl ;
}

template<typename T>
void f(T&&t)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(t)) ;
}

void h(X &&t)
{
    g(t) ;
}


int main()
{
    X x;
    f(x);   // 1
    f(X()); // 2
    //h(x);  //compile error 
    h(X()); // 3
}
```

According to the author describe below :

When you combine rvalue references with function templates you get an interesting interaction: if the type of a function parameter is an rvalue reference to a template type parameter then the type parameter is deduce to be an lvalue reference if an lvalue is passed, and a plain type otherwise...

The results output of this test are :

```
t in g is lvalue
t in g is rvalue
t in g is lvalue
```

f(x) get "t in g is lvalue"  is just like expected !!

f(X()) get "t in g is rvalue" , yes,that is what std::forward used for

h(X()) get "t in g is lvalue" , this is my question ,as you can see that function h 
is not a template function , as the author describe "When you combine rvalue references with function templates you get an interesting interaction"  is not the case , still 
this function output "t in g is lvalue" , means this interesting interaction happen not just in template function , also to normal function , too !!

if I change code to :

```
void h(X &&t)
{
    g(std::forward<X>(t)) ;
}
```

I will got "t in g is rvalue" !!!

Accorind to test , May I said that the author describe "When you combine rvalue references with function templates you get an interesting interaction" actually not only to template function , it also apply to normal function , or my english is not good , so I can not catch this description right ?!

Edit :

```
void h(X &&t)
{
    g(t) ;
}

void h(X &t)
{
    g(t) ;
}

h(x);      //get "t in g is lvalue"
h(X());    //get "t in g is lvalue"

=====================================================

void h(X &&t)
{
    g(std::forward<X>(t)) ;
}

void h(X &t)
{
    g(std::forward<X>(t)) ;
}

h(x);      //get "t in g is rvalue"
h(X());    //get "t in g is rvalue"
```

Look like only in template function , I will get the cprrect usage of std::forward !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `h(X &&)`, the type of `t` is an r-value reference to `X`, but named variables are always treated as l-values.  So, even though `t` is an `X &&`, `t` can not bind directly to an `X &&` parameter, but only an `X &` parameter.  This is for safety, since a named variable can (and often will) be used over and over again.  You don't want the first usage of a variable to pilfer it, even if it did originally bind to an r-value.  Subsequent uses would see the pilfered value, which will very easily lead to broken logic in code.

If you know a variable is an r-value (or more to the point, if you know you're done with it, whether it's an l-value or an r-value), the way to pass it on as an r-value is by using `move()`.  The purpose of `forward<T>()` is for generic code, when you don't know whether the original value should be pilfered or not.  If you were to use `move()` in a template, you may accidentally pilfer an l-value.  So you use `forward<T>()` instead, which will resolve to a harmless pass-through if `T` is an l-value type, and will essentially become equivalent to `move()` if `T` is a non-reference or an r-value reference.

Note that in your **edit**, your second overload of `h` (that is, `h(X &t)`) is using `forward<>` incorrectly.  The type of `t` in that situation is `X &`, so you should be using `forward<X&>(t)`.  If you did that, you would find that `t` is passed on as an l-value.  However, in your two overloads of `h`, you can see that in the first, you have an r-value reference, and in the second you have an l-value reference.  (There's no template deduction involved, so you know the types.)  Therefore, you might as well use `move()` directly in your first overload, and not use anything in your second.  The purpose of `forward<T>()` is to harvest information from the template deduction to determine whether it was bound to (and deduced as) an l-value or an r-value.